# Ember Data and mapping JSON objects

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have truly searched and I have not found a decent example of using the serializer to get objects from a differently formatted JSON response. My reason for not changing the format of the JSON response is outlined here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/security/#json-security.

I'm not very good with javascript yet so I had a hard time understanding the hooks in the serialize_json.js or maybe I should be using mapping (I just don't know). So here is an example of my JSON response for many objects:

```
{
  "total_pages": 1, 
  "objects": [
     {
      "is_completed": true, 
      "id": 1, 
      "title": "I need to eat"
    }, 
    {
      "is_completed": false, 
      "id": 2, 
      "title": "Hey does this work"
    }, 
    {
      "is_completed": false, 
      "id": 3, 
      "title": "Go to sleep"
    }, 
  ], 
  "num_results": 3, 
  "page": 1
}
```

When ember-data tries to use this I get the following error:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.1
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1
DEBUG: -------------------------------
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key total_pages but you have no mapping for it
```

Which totally makes when you look at my code for the data store:

```
Todos.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        mappings: {objects: "Todos.Todo"},
        namespace: 'api'
    })
});
```

My question is how do I deal with `total_pages`, `num_results` and `page`? And by deal, I mean ignore so I can just map the `objects` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All root properties you return in your JSON result are mapped to a DS.Model in Ember Data. You should not return properties that are not modelled or you should model them.

If you want to get rid of the error you should make an empty model for the properties you don't use.

Read more [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-root)

Why are you returning properties you don't want to use? Or is it out of your control?

Comment: I am going to return properties that are not modeled and I don't want to model them.

Comment: I could modify the response, but I know I should be able to do this with the JSONSerializer. I just don't know how. I mean that's the point of it: to take JSON that is 'irregular' and convert it to something ember-data can use.

Comment: @Willem de Wit - what about the _id and __v properties that are added by database? Do we need to model those?

Comment: @Keith when those properties are part of your JSON response you should model them. The `_id` (and `_ids`) properties are interpreted as foreign keys to other objects. When you have `post_id: 10` Ember looks for a `Post` with `id` of 10.

Answer (score 1):

Ember is fairly opinionated about how things are done. Ember data is no exception. The Ember team works towards certain standards that it thinks is best, which is, in my opinion, a good thing.

Check out [this post](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/03/ember-data-progress-update.html) on where ember is going. TL;DR because there are so many varying implementations of api calls, they're setting their efforts towards supporting the [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/).

From my understanding, there is no easy way to do what you're asking. Your best bet is to write your own custom adapter and serialized. This shouldn't be too hard to do, and has been done before. I recommend you having a look at the [Tastypie adapter](https://github.com/escalant3/ember-data-tastypie-adapter) used for Python's Django Tastypie

Answer (score 1):

The way to accomplish this is with a custom serializer. If all your data is returned from the server in this format you could simply create `ApplicationSerializer` like this:

```
DS.RESTSerilizer.extend({
  normalizePayload: function(type, payload) {
     delete payload.total_pages;
     delete payload.num_results;
     delete payload.page;
     return payload;
  }
});
```

That should allow Ember Data to consume your API seamlessly.